# How to read data immediantly from client?

Tags: java, netty

How can i get data  immediantly  from client in server netty 4.

In moment when i sending data to client ,client send me  data.But handler (method `channelRead()`)received data only after server sended  a data

The problem i will show in a process list, i use netty 4:

1. get data from client
2. start calculate response
3. send some service data to client as (`ctx.writeAndFlush()`) (ok)
4. continue calculate response
5. should get data from client (here a problem)
6. send calculated response to client(sends ok).

My Code:
Handler

```
 @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        logger.debug("Start read handler " + ctx.channel().toString());
        ByteBuf b = (ByteBuf) msg;
     ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer( new Test.send(ctx,b) );
}
```

Test

```
 public class Test
 public byte[] send(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,ByteBuf b){
 // start calculates
 ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(some data)); - its ok

 // calculates .. (during here i should get data from client but nothing   happens. Why does  the channel blocks  receiving data ? ) 
 return response;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have an ChannelInboundHandler which will be notified once the response was received. Remember everything in netty is non-blocking.